# Gulp, Sass processing - stops at 1 file

Tags: sass, gulp, materialize

The gulp.src function returns 32 files but only 1 file is returned from sass().

I'm new to gulp and was hoping someone could point out why all 32 files aren't being piped into the sass() function or why only 1 file is being processed and return by sass().

gulp.src(folderFound.path + "/*.scss") //32 files found output log shown below

.pipe( sass() ) //Only 1 file returned from sass() to save as .css

```
/* File: gulpfile.js */

// grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var path = require('path');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var recursiveFolder = require('gulp-recursive-folder');

var options = {
    pathToFolder: './sass/',
    readFolder: './sass/',
    target: './Compiled'
}

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('generateTree', recursiveFolder({
    base: options.pathToFolder,
    exclude: [    // exclude the debug modules from thus build 
        'debug-modules'
    ] 
}, function(folderFound){

return gulp.src(folderFound.path + "/*.scss")     
    .on("data", function(test) { 
   gutil.log("Found Files: ", test.path);
})
   .pipe(

     sass().on('error',

     function(test) { 
   gutil.log("error: ", test.path);
})
     )
.on("data", function(test) { 
   gutil.log("SASS Processed: ", test.path);
})

   .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));   
     ;
}));


[16:18:40] Using gulpfile d:\Materialize\materialize-src\gulpfile.js
[16:18:40] Starting 'generateTree'...
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\materialize.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_buttons.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\date_picker\_default.date.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_checkboxes.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_cards.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\date_picker\_default.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_file-input.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_carousel.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\date_picker\_default.time.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_forms.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_chips.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_input-fields.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_collapsible.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_radio-buttons.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_color.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_range.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_dropdown.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_select.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_global.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\forms\_switches.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_grid.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_icons-material-design.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_materialbox.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_mixins.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_modal.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_navbar.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_normalize.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_prefixer.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_preloader.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_roboto.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_sideNav.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_slider.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_table_of_contents.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_tabs.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_toast.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_tooltip.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_typography.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_variables.scss
[16:18:40] Found Files:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\components\_waves.scss
**[16:18:40] SASS Processed:  d:\Materialize\materialize-src\sass\materialize.css**
[16:18:40] Finished 'generateTree' after 162 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your .scss files are what are called "partials" except materialize.css.

"**Partials**

You can create partial Sass files that contain little snippets of CSS that you can include in other Sass files. This is a great way to modularize your CSS and help keep things easier to maintain. A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file **and that it should not be generated into a CSS file**. Sass partials are used with the @import directive."

from [sass language guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

So you are getting expected behavior - partials, starting with an underscore, do not produce an output file but are used to be included within another file.

Comment: And that would explain the hefty file size of the single outputed .css file. Thank you very much.